# an example of Xquery with "AND" operator , please

Tags: xquery

I think Xquery has not the "AND" operator and i cant do this:

**if** node1 = xxx **and** node2 = yyy **and** node3 = zzz **then** replace node3 with www

Answer (score 7):

XQuery has And Operator which is "and". it has OR operator also "or".

```
let $d := <Employee>
<Name>Test</Name>
<ID>1909239</ID>
<Address>test Add </Address>
<Email>test@test.net</Email>
<Department>Dept 1</Department>
<Department>Dept 2</Department>
<Department>Dept 3</Department>
<Department>Dept 4</Department>
<Department>Dept 5</Department>
```

```
return if( ($d//*:Department[1]/text() = 'Dept 1') and ($d//*:Department[1]/text() = 'Dept 2') ) then fn:true() else fn:false()
```

Comment: This coded tested against MarkLogic Server. but XQuery is set to W3C standards.

Answer (score 0):

http://x-query.com/pipermail/talk/2004-November/000358.html

<<
There's no such operator as `"&="` in XQuery. I think you need the
contains() function instead, although you might want matches().

So I think your query should look like:

```
let $query :=
  if ($ttl != "") then (
    for $entries in collection($collctn)//TEI.2
                      [contains(., $kwds) and
                       descendant::head[contains(., $ttl)]
    return (
      if ($entries/@id = "ppp.00271") then (
        ...
      )
      else if ($entries/@id = "ppp.00237") then (
        ...
      )
      else if ($entries/@id = "ppp.00473") then (
        ...
      )
      else (
        ...
      )
  )
  else if (...) then (
    ...
  )
  else (
    ...
  )
```